Getting Project Build Error: Non-parseable POM
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.apitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sqlconnector</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>sring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I am not able to correct this error. Getting it at the </dependencies> tag and the error is being shown on line 24.

Your sample looks like there are parts of the XML missing or might got lost in composing the post. You might want to post the whole POM as otherwise it is somewhat hard to give any meaningful advice. I would guess that based on the error message that one or more XML tags are missing or are misaligned

pom.xml
you can compare my pom.xml with your pom.xml yourself.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.apitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sqlconnector</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

some error
error - 1
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>sring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<dependency>  <--- Here Wrong , should be </dependency>
<dependency>

error - 2
</dependency>
*** `<dependency>` is missing here. ***
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

error - 3
<artifactId>sring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

typo: sring -> spring
TIPS:
Use https://start.spring.io
(1) Use https://start.spring.io/ to help you create the project and pom.xml.
(2) To add jpa, just click the button ADD DEPENDENCIES..., and then enter jpa, then Spring Data JPA will pop up, you just need to click to join.
In this way, you can avoid the problem of mismatched xml tags or typos.
(3) In addition, you can also use the Meld GUI comparison tool to compare the pom.xml generated through Spring Boot Init with your pom.xml.
(4) I just tested it, you can also directly ask AI this question: "Check the content errors of this pom.xml: paste your pom.xml here " , and then take a look at the errors AI checks for you.
